# Why is nth-child(2) selecting children of children too?

Tags: jquery, css

This fucntion

```
$("#sidebar div:nth-child(2)").removeClass("stick-after")
```

is selecting as deep as html goes.

Why nth-child(2) is selecting like that, and what is to be used to select only first level children?

Comment: Because `div` is selecting multiple descendant divs, each of which are the nth child of something.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? You've written a _descendant_ selector, not a child selector.

Comment: You probably want `> div:nth-child(2)`, but it's hard to say without seeing your markup.